# Right-sided derivative of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, trigonometry, power-series

Let define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such as

$f(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x=0$

Prove that $f$ has right-sided all-order derivatives in $0$.

**My approach:**

I find out that $f$ can be written as the power series 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^k
$$
which has an infinite radius of convergence so the $n$-th derivative of $f$ in zero would be
$$
f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(2n+1)!}
$$
but I do not know how to connect these facts with the right-sided derivative of this function

Answer (score 3):

Since$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots,$$you have$$\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x}=1-\frac x{3!}+\frac{x^2}{5!}-\frac{x^3}{7!}+\cdots$$when $x\geqslant0$, from which it follows that, indeed, $f$ has right-sided derivatives of all orders at $0$.

Comment: what theoem stands for your statement that $f$ has right-sided derivatives of all orders?

Comment: The theorem that says that if a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$ centered at $a$ has non-zero radius of convergence, then $(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+):\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}=a_n$.

Comment: But I know only this theorem for the normal limits not sided one. How to connect this theorem with this special case?

Comment: If the derivatives exist for both sides, then one-sided derivatives exit too.

Comment: But what theorem (name) stands for that we can connect the given series (that converges for all values, also these smaller than zero) with the initial function (which can be defined only for positive numbers)

Comment: Not all theorems have names and all I did was to do some algebraic computations in order to prove that the sum of the series that I provided is equal to $\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x}$.